# Detecting Volume Key press on BlackBerry 10 Java Android Runtime

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-android

I am trying to port my Android app to the BlackBerry 10, and the detection of the Volume Key press does not seem to work - the key press does not result in my code getting invoked. Here's my code snippet:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  { 
   if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) { 
       // We override the volume key to trigger a special event in our app 
       return true;
   } else {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
   }
}
```

That code above works on an Android phone.

Is there another way for an Android app on BB10 to detect the Volume key press?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently detecting the Volume Key press is not supported even for the Native BB10 platform - from the [BlackBerry support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/onKeyDown-support/td-p/2469487)